# Template with Required Attribute Knowledge

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

This seems very basic but I'm struggling to find a solution I'm happy with at the minute. All I want to do is add a class with the name "Required" to any fields that have a required property against them so:

```
public class Dummy{
  [Required]
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Would be called with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
```

and would output something like

```
<input id="Name *Data-VAL and other attribs* class="Required" />
```

With all the inbuilt unobtrusive goodness etc. I'm using Razor and MVC 3.  Any help much appretiated

Comment: Yes so what's the problem here? There's nothing wrong with what you've shown in the code above.

Comment: Hi Kassem I want the required class to be output at the minute it is not

Comment: What do you mean by output? Please try the code I provided below, and read the tutorial I linked to. If that did not solve your problem, try to elaborate so we could provide more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which explains how you could write a custom [DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider.aspx) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; //You need to import this namespace

public class Dummy {
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Further reference: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs